# select from 2 table based on count of 3rd table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, inner-join

I have 3 tables. member reimbursement and receipt. I want to display member's first name,reimbursement total that has a receipt. For example

member

```
member_id   member_name
1           luffy
2           zoro
3           nami
```

reimbursement

```
reimburse_id member_id reimburse_total
1            1         5000
2            2         10000
3            3         10000
```

receipt

```
receipt_id  reimburse_id reimburse_price reimburse_no
1            1           2500            2012232
2            1           2500            2012123
3            2           5000            2012454
4            2           5000            2012565
```

I want to display all reimbursement of the member which has receipt. In this case the select query should return like this

```
name   No. of reimburse total
luffy         1         5000 
zoro          1         10000
nami          0         0
```

So far this i what i got

```
SELECT member.member_name,
       COU­NT(distinct reimbursement.reimbu­rse_id) as nor,
       SUM(distinct reimbursement.reimbu­rse_total)
FROM member INNER JOIN
     reimbursement 
     ON member.member_id = reim­bursement.member_id INNER JOIN
     receipt
     ON reimbursement.reimbu­rse_id=receipt.reimb­urse_id
GROUP BY member.memberID
```

but i got the wrong total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  This is a little strange because you are only using `receipt` to determine if the values should be used.  One method is `LEFT JOIN` and some conditional logic:

```
SELECT m.member_name,
       COUNT(rr.reimburse_id) as nor,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rr.reimburse_id IS NOT NULL THEN reimburse_total ELSE 0 END) as reimbu­rse_total
FROM member m LEFT JOIN
     reimbursement r
     ON m.member_id = r.member_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT rr.reimburse_id
      FROM receipt rr
     ) rr
     ON r.reimbu­rse_id = rr.reimb­urse_id
GROUP BY m.memberID, m.member_name;
```

The logic behind this query is to use the `receipt` table only to determine if a reimbursement is available.  The `select distinct` removes duplicates.  Then the `left join` and `case` determine if there are matches to the table.

Comment: sorry for late response. I've got to check your answer please wait

Comment: Sir it works fine. Can you explain what you've done? It is completely different from what i know

Comment: sir i dont get this line how will the query check every receipt record? "CASE WHEN rr.reimburse_id IS NOT NULL THEN reimburse_total ELSE 0 END"

Comment: That only adds up the total when a record exists in the receipt table for that reimbursement.